# Which translation of "just" does German use to imply some minor/short activity?

Tags: translation

I often use expressions like:

> I'm just eating

or:

> I'm just exercising

etc. where the *just* means that I'm doing some small/short-lived activity that I will be finished with soon.

Does German use *nur* or *einfach* in a similar fashion? Or does it have some more commonly used way of expressing this?

Comment: errr.... hochdeutsch?

Comment: For the first I'd personally say something llike"Ich ess' nur gerade 'was"

Comment: For me, it's "bloß"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different things you might say in different contexts to imply that an action is short-lived and will be finished soon.

> Ich esse *nur schnell* was.
>   Ich fahre *mal kurz* einkaufen.
>   Ich trainiere *noch schnell zuende/fertig*.
>   Ich wische *eben* durch.
>   Ich rauche *gerade noch* eine.
>   Ich mache *bloß noch* die Maschine an.

And more can probably be added by other users. (The third probably doesn't really fit here; it's more of an *I'll just **finish** something*; but they're closely related.)

While many are used interchangeably, not all can be switched. *Ich esse eben was* has a different meaning to it than *ich esse nur schnell was*.

Note that the suggestions you made, *nur* and *einfach* would be wrong in this context. *Nur* alone would be taken to mean *only* (*ich esse nur was*), and *einfach* would be something more like *simply*.

Also note that different versions are preferred over others in different parts of the German-speaking world. There are quite a few that would raise many eyebrows in certain areas for being uncommon.

The best suggestion I can give anybody wanting to learn rules is to shadow a German speaker and copy them.

Comment: I would add "bloß" to the list...

Comment: @Gerhard added.

Comment: Dialect/regional note: #2 "mal" is a colloquial shortening of hochdeutsch "einmal" - Austrian variant would be "amal". #4 and #6 are nonexistent/unusable in Austria.

Comment: @wolfgang Yes that's generally the problem. What's true for Austria is often true for Bavaria, sometimes true for Swabia and often wrong in Prussia. But that's German. I added a sentence to reflect that.