# "We're just taking a look" - Expression

Tags: english-to-german, phrase

Let us say you are shopping for clothes and one of the people in the section approaches you and asks "kommen Sie zurecht?" or something like that.

How would you express "oh we're just taking a look", "looking around".?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say

> „Danke, wir schauen nur“

or

> „Vielen Dank, ich melde mich wenn ich 'ne Frage hab'“

Comment: @Downvoter: Please add a comment how to improve this post.

Comment: @Jan... indeed!

Answer (score 7):

The literal translation, which works perfectly in this case, would be:

> Danke, ich schaue mich nur um.

The verb in question is *umschauen*.

(I *think* this works with *umsehen* and *umgucken* as well, but as a Southerner, I don't use those verbs.)

For additional ways on how to say *just*, [see this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/which-translation-of-just-does-german-use-to-imply-some-minor-short-activity).

Comment: Great!. I am in Bayern so your southerner Einzelheiten are welcome